# Split Column at leading numbers only

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I was able to work out how to split my column with numbers and letters, and have found solutions to split numbers and letters. But I have the problem of losing all the numbers that follow the leading numbers/digits and can not find a solution (and also still learning how to use regex).

Quick example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['Col1','Col2'],
                ['1','05MW'],
                ['2','16MW'],
                ['3','05SW1'],
                ['4','05SW2']])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,:])

df[['Col2', 'id']] = df['Col2'].str.extract('(\d+)([A-Za-z]*)', expand=True)
```

Gives:

```
print (df)
  Col1 Col2  id
1    1   05  MW
2    2   16  MW
3    3   05  SW
4    4   05  SW
```

However, I don't want to lose anything, including numbers, that follow the leading numbers. I  am trying to achieve this output:

```
print (df)
  Col1 Col2  id
1    1   05  MW
2    2   16  MW
3    3   05  SW1
4    4   05  SW2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `0-9` for parse also numbers:

```
df[['Col2', 'id']] = df['Col2'].str.extract('(\d+)([A-Za-z0-9]*)', expand=True)
```

Or use `.*` for parse all values:

```
df[['Col2', 'id']] = df['Col2'].str.extract('(\d+)(.*)', expand=True)
```

---

```
print (df)
  Col1 Col2   id
1    1   05   MW
2    2   16   MW
3    3   05  SW1
4    4   05  SW2
```

Comment: `(.*)` was what I was stuck searching for. I didn't even think to add `0-9`. Seems so simple once you see it in practice.